# How to fix "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to create a json object in asp.net mvc 5 .
here is my code. but when i run this, it gives a message "object reference not set to an instance of an object". please help me with this. thanks

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
        AmountTransaction amount = new AmountTransaction();
        amount.endUserId = "93786853033";
        amount.paymentAmount.chargingInformation.amount = "1";
        amount.paymentAmount.chargingInformation.code = "1";
        amount.paymentAmount.chargingInformation.currency = "AFA";
        amount.paymentAmount.chargingInformation.description = "charge it";
        amount.referenceCode = "1";
        amount.transactionStatus = "Charged";
        var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(amount);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        return View();
    }
```

and my classes

```
public class ChargingInformation
{
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentAmount
{
    public ChargingInformation chargingInformation { get; set; }
}

public class AmountTransaction
{
    public string endUserId { get; set; }
    public PaymentAmount paymentAmount { get; set; }
    public string referenceCode { get; set; }
    public string transactionStatus { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public AmountTransaction amountTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have not indicated which line throws the exception. No doubt on `amount.paymentAmount.chargingInformation.amount = "1";` since `paymentAmount` is `null` and you cannot assign a value to a property of `null`

Comment: can you please tell me what the correct code example?

Comment: Read the duplicate! You need to initialize `paymentAmount` - `amount.paymentAmount = new PaymentAmount();` before you assign a value (and ditto for `chargingInformation`)

Comment: please give me the correct block of code please...

Comment: i did it. you are perfect ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `paymentAmount` field on `AmountTransaction` is throwing a `null` reference because it hasn't been set to a new `PaymentAmount` instance.

Same with `ChargingInformation` on that class.

Comment: can you please give the the correct code of it please

Comment: Thank you so much . i fixed it with your help ;-)